# Distinguish Between Events Triggered by User Input Vs. Code Behind UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, uwp

I have a CheckBox in a UWP app that is manipulated by both the user and code behind. When the user checks it, I do want the `Checked` event to fire. However, when the code behind checks it (like below), I don't want it to fire.

```
checkBoxExample.isChecked = true; //The Checked event should not fire.
```

I figured I would get this information from either the sender (object) or e (RoutedEventArgs) but it isn't there.

Comment: have you thought about adding a boolean field to UWP similar to the following:

Comment: I think you can just track `Tapped` event instead of `Checked` and then get the new value in the event handler directly like `var isChecked = checkbox.isChecked;`

Comment: @AndreyAshikhmin I think that the `Tapped` event should not be used, it would work only for touch, pen and mouse input. I have mentioned this in my answer

Comment: It is a quite good example why you have to use MVVM instead of placing your logic directly into code-behind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a flag that you then set to avoid processing the event:

```
private bool _checkedFromCode = false;

private void CheckboxChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ( !_checkedFromCode )
    {
        //your logic
    }
}
```

Now when setting the `IsChecked` from code:

```
_checkedFromCode = true;
checkBoxExample.IsChecked = true;
_checkedFromCode = false;
```

The event will still fire, but you can limit the processing to only when it actually is from the user interaction.

Alternatively, you could create a custom derived version of `CheckBox` that would have a custom event only for this scenario.

**RE:`Tapped`** **event**: The suggested solution with `Tapped` event would not work as you should not presume the user is using touch, mouse or pen, as Windows 10 works with any kind of input, so the only reliable event is the `Checked` event. It should not matter which input type you use. This is especially true to make your app accessible and inclusive. Keyboard, for example, does not cause `Tapped` event.

Comment: Could you provide examples of input that will not raise Tapped event but still allow user to check a checkbox?

Comment: Keyboard primarily, which will be the main input for users with limitations - if you create a blank UWP app, put a  `CheckBox` on the page, add a `Tapped` event to it, set a breakpoint inside, launch the app and press Tab and then Space - the `CheckBox` will be checked but the event will not fire

Comment: I tend to as well :-D .

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant/built-in method, but this works great too. Thank you.

Comment: @MartinZikmund Just recently I have been working with the generic ButtonBase.Command property. It turns out that commands are only fired by user interaction, and therefore do not require any flags. Furthermore, Microsoft documentation recommends that when possible, commands should be used instead of event handlers to improve performance and efficiency. Commands are actually pretty cool!  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/commanding